# Split Database: Is It Possible to Append Database Name to All Queries?

Tags: magento-1.9, database

Magento 2 EE comes with a [split database feature](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/multi-master/multi-master.html), where three master databases with their own distinct tables work for the platform. Has anybody tried to do something similar in Magento 1 (CE)?

I'm tinkering around with this idea to see how (in)feasible this is to have one "main" DB and "secondary" DB in M1. However, I quickly came across an issue. For example, if you want to split customers to the secondary DB, you can assign a separate connection for the customer module, but the problem is that some `SELECT` queries on the customers are joined with tables, like `eav_attribute`, from the main DB. Opening a customer in the admin is an example.

The solution to this *immediate problem* would be to append the database name to all queries constructed, but it seems tricky to track down exactly where I need to do this. I'm currently looking around this appraoch. Isolated customer load and saves are working. Any comments from experience or ideas are welcome!